# Derivative of nonsmooth functions

Tags: derivatives, subgradient

If a function is continuous but nonsmooth at point x = a, but has a finite derivative = 4 at x = a - $\epsilon$ and a finite derivative = 7 at $x = a + \epsilon$, both in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.

Under what conditions (if any) is it appropriate to write that the derivative at x=a is $3 * \delta(x - a)$?

Or do we say the derivative is infinity at $x = a$, or do we say the derivative is undefined at $x = a$?

Comment: You can use the delta function to describe the derivative of a step function.  Since f'(x) that has a step, it would be the second derivative that you might describe with a delta.  The derivative itself is undefined at $a.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can say (in the distributional sense) that the derivative of a "function" is $3\delta(x-a)$ if there's a jump discontinuity of height $3$ at $x=a$.

In your case I would say it's more appropriate to simply say that the derivative is undefined there.